# Video Rendering Not Working on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, video, safari

I have a website: https://www.remooble.com that generally loads a nice, full screen video of a lady wiping off a wall after her kid shmutzed it up with a marker. This video loads fine on Chrome and FF, but it either doesn't load or loads really messy and small in Safari and IE.

If anyone has any insight as to what's causing this issue I would be really appreciative of your feedback. As it is, we're not able to locate the issue or the fix.

Thank you!!

Comment: It seems to look the same, small at the top of the screen but clear video, in both Safari and Chrome when I test it.

Comment: Thanks for looking Mick. Unfortunately it's supposed to be full screen. If you reload a couple of times it should load full (Chrome, FF)). However in IE, no matter how many times you reload, it doesn't work :/